# Filepicker.io - "Select All" button for selecting multiple images

Tags: filepicker.io

Is it possible to add a select all button to the filepicker.io dialog so the users don't have to click each one or shift+click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filepicker Developer here. There isn't a way to do that at the moment. I'll let the product team know that there seems to be some friction for your users as they upload a lot of files. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's clearly top priority to implement this feature, I thought I'd figure a way to do it myself... Having to click each file (of over 3,000) to add them individually is just plain asinine. Not implementing this feature since it was requested in 2013 and it's now 2015, two years later, is just plain neglect and short sighted. Shame on FilePicker...

1) Open the upload dialog inside the website calling FilePicker (in my case, Blacks.ca) using Chrome

2) Open Developer Tools and the Console tab

3) Switch the target dropdown to the 'dialog.filepicker.io' entry

4) Browse to the file service of your choice and get it to show the files (scroll down repeatedly) you want to import (use the filter tab to keep import quantities under control). I could do 1000 at a time, it would crash the tab doing more at a time.

5) Once all the files you want to import are loaded in the scroll pane. Enter the following code into the console window and hit enter.

```
var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName("fp__wrapper");
console.log('length: ' + class1.length);
for (var i = 0; i < class1.length; i++) {
    var button1 = class1[i].getElementsByTagName("button");
    console.log('length2: ' + button1.length);
    var count = 0
    for (var j = 0; j < button1.length; j++) {
        if (button1[j].className == "btn--cover") {
            count++;
            console.log(count + ' ' + button1[j].parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML);
            button1[j].click();
        }
    }
}
```

It will give you feedback in the console as it clicks each button. However, there is a server call for each one so it will take some time to process after clicking all the buttons. Be patient.

Once they are all selected, click the 'Import' button in the bottom right corner of the import window. While it's transferring the files from your file service of choice to FilePicker, click the upvote button on this comment and write an email to FilePicker commenting about the lack of a 'select all button'. Finally, have a blissful rest of your day (that you reclaimed instead of clicking each file).